# Do I need to handle raising of documented exceptions when implementing interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, exception

I'm creating a custom C# collection by implementing ICollection in my class and have noticed some of the methods defined by the interface have exceptions documented i.e. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0efx51xw(v=vs.110).aspx

None of the examples or documentation I've seen for implementing interfaces seem to talk about needing to implement raising exceptions. Whenever the documentation for a method in an interface shows exceptions could be raised by the method should I be checking for each of these conditions and raising the exceptions within my implementation code?

Comment: In the case you linked to, these are all exceptions the framework would throw - null array, array index less than 0 and number of elements in the source collection is greater than the available space in the end destination.  It's not that the interface is implementing exception handling (it can't) - it's simply letting developers know that these exceptions could occur and should be handled.  By the way, IMO, it doesn't mean the developer needs to implement try-catch - the first two at least could be handled by properly written code.

Comment: Tim - thanks for your response. I was thinking more if it was an indication that I should be checking for those conditions in my method implementation (i.e. array == null) and then throwing the ArgumentNullException myself. It does make sense though that the documentation is just indicating which exceptions the framework could throw if those conditions arose.

Comment: It happens to be true that the most common implementation (`Array.Copy`) would naturally throw the appropriate exceptions, so you wouldn't need your own checks. I think the important thing is that your implementation does *not* throw any exceptions *other* than the ones that are documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When documenting an interface, it is common to include  xml documentation to indicate the exceptions that may be thrown by implementations. This doesn't mean that implementations MUST be able to throw these, just that they MAY throw them.

See Liskov's Substitution Principle. Specifically "No new exceptions should be thrown by methods of the subtype, except where those exceptions are themselves subtypes of exceptions thrown by the methods of the supertype." -http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle